# Counting rows from Where Clause and display every count in a different column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Hi I have a MySql Query as follows:

```
Select Count(*),status,time from table where Status in (2,3,8) group by status,time
```

The Output is ok i get something like

Count Status time

10 - 1 -      2014

10 -   2    -   2014

19  -  1   -   2015

11   -  2 - 2015

But what i would like to have is something like

Count of Status1  -   Count of Status2  - Time

10 - 10 - 2014

19 - 11 - 2015

Is there a nice and efficient way to do since since my database has about 1 mio records. I want to use this data to show it in a table without further manipulation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(`Status` = 1,1,0) ) CountOfStatus1,SUM(IF(`Status` = 2,1,0) ) CountOfStatus2,TIME FROM TABLE WHERE STATUS IN (1,2) GROUP BY TIME
```

You will need to adjust it for whatever statuses you want to see.